# How to get profile data from facebook using passport.js authentication?

Tags: node.js, facebook-authentication, passport.js

In the below code the 'console.log('this does not print!')' statement does not execute. It should execute according to the FacebookStrategy.

```
passport.use( new FacebookStrategy({clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID, clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, callbackURL: "/home"}, function(identifier, profile, done) {

process.nextTick(function () {
  console.log(' This does not print!');
  return done(null, profile);
  }
);}));
```

Basically, the authentication thru passport-facebook takes place but I am not able to recover any profile data.

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.user);
    res.render('home', {user: req.user});
});
```

The above prints 'undefined' which means that the above app.get(...) did not receive the facebook profile data.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anyway to save (get) facebook profile data after authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above

```
callbackURL: "/home"
```

is wrongly declared. It should be:

```
callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback"
```

for more on this discussion https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/47